# Type Error "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am in Node trying to send a http call to an endpoint. I'm not getting any response, and im certain I have set something up incorrectly. My request worked on postman. Any help woud be awesome!

```js
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

curlUpdate = function curlUpdate() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "www.example.com", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send({
        FirstName: "john",
        LastName: "doe",
        MerchantSessionID: "817281271",
        DateOfBirth: "12,24,1985",
        ProductTypeID: "xxxxxxxxx"
    });
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
```

Comment: I think you should pass a string to `send` not an object. Try `JSON.stringify`ing the object before passing it to `send`.

Comment: Yup, that seems to work, thank you! @ibrahimmahrir

Answer (score 3):

You just need to wrap your object with `JSON.stringify()`.

So your xhr.send will looks like:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        FirstName: "john",
        LastName: "doe",
        MerchantSessionID: "817281271",
        DateOfBirth: "12,24,1985",
        ProductTypeID: "xxxxxxxxx"
    }));
```

P.S. don't forget to point address (now it's `www.example.com` in your code) to correct endpoint.